# How to move Excel 2010 data from rows into 2 columns only?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have the average daily values of flow for 30 years organized as follows:

[image]

Could you please let me know how could I organize the previous data in two columns only as shown below?

[image]

Many thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: can you post up your data in a more readable fashion? Screenshots might be helpful. And a mockup of what desired output would be like

Comment: @PsychoData Many thanks for your help. I would like to post a printscreen of my data, however I can't as my reputation isn't 10 (only 1)

Comment: linky then? maybe?

Comment: your good to go now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `VLOOKUP` for this:

`=VLOOKUP(DAY(A1), your_table_ref, MONTH(A1)+1, FALSE)`

Here I assume cell A1 contains a date. Replace `your_table_ref` with the reference to your big table of numbers - don't forget to add dollar signs (e.g. $A$1:$Z$26). The first argument finds the correct row and the third argument the correct column. The FALSE is there to ensure an exact match. Fill Down and Bob's your uncle!

*EDIT*: assuming (for simplicity) your date in the left column contains the correct year, you should modify your formula to shift the lookup table depending on the year, something like:

`=VLOOKUP(DAY(A1), OFFSET(your_table_ref, (YEAR(A1)-start_year)*37, 0), MONTH(A1)+1, FALSE)`

since there are 37 rows between each data set.

It's more difficult (but not impossible) to have the year and month headings in your left column as well, as you've shown. Much easier to just have a continuous list of dates, with the year included.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. I've tried to solve it following your formula but it didn't work. Could you please check the attached excel file and the formula I have tried to use? https://www.dropbox.com/s/ia9690yf6xx9qd0/Flow_Q2.xlsx
Any suggestions would be much appreciated. I totally agree with you that continuous list of dates with the year included is much more easier and that's what I need exactly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The main problem seemed to be that all your numbers were stored as text, with a tab character following them. I've fixed this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24985915/Flow_Q2.xlsx

Comment: Could you please let me know if there is any way to delete the months and years headers from Pivot Table to get a continuous list of dates with the year included? 
http://superuser.com/questions/679920/how-to-delete-the-headers-in-the-pivot-tables