# How to delete the headers in the Pivot Tables?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

After creating the Pivot Table shown below

[image]

I want to get a continuous list of dates with the year included as shown below

[image]

In order to get the data organized as shown above, I have copied and pasted all the values from the Pivot Table into a new sheet, deleted all the years and months headers and then organized all the values as a continuous list of dates with the year included. However, following the procedures above is time taking. Could you please let me know if there is any way to delete the years and months (headers)? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is copy-pasting from the pivot table the quickest way to get your list of dates? I would have thought the easiest way to do that would be to type the first two dates and use the fill handle to do the rest.

Failing that, what you need to do is use filtering. With both columns selected, click **Filter** from the **Sort & Filter** dropdown in the **Home** ribbon. You'll get a dropdown next to each column; you can use this to either delete the rows you don't want, or copy-paste the rows you do want somewhere else. Or you can sort them into an order which will place the unwanted rows at the top.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer. I do appreciate your time and help. You saved my time :)

Comment: Is it possible to fill in the dates after the filter?

Comment: Yes, you can add anything before or after you've filtered the data. I only suggested a filter as a temporary ruse to get rid of the rows you don't want; after you've done that, you can un-filter it again.

Comment: Could you please check this question?

http://superuser.com/questions/680760/how-to-delete-days-with-no-data
You could check the dataset through this link if you please
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rlrp78lj0jfk51d/Flow_Q.xlsx