# How to delete days with no data?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table, date

I have the flow data for 49 years for 15 min interval. I've used pivot table to get the daily average value of flow.

[image]

After copy-pasting from pivot table and using filter to remove the blank flow cells (monthly and yearly headers), I filled in the dates to get a continuous list of the dates with the year included. However, many days have no data as shown above (e.g. 20-Jan, 26-Jan and 9-Feb). As a result, I had to check the whole data and delete those days with no data. Is there any way I can get a list of days with years included for the days with data only?

[image]

You can check the whole dataset through this link
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rlrp78lj0jfk51d/Flow_Q.xlsx

Answer (score 1):

In Excel there is an option to set up an auto filter on selected rows. After you are doing that you could select the filter for non-empty data (in the relevant row) and all your empty lines will be removed (on view).

Comment: @UserUser       
Thanks for your time and help. I deleted the empty rows using the filter. I want to delete the cells which have dates with no data. For example: there is no data for 9th of Feb. However, after filling in the dates to have a continuous list of dates with the years included, I got 9th of Feb "in column A" (which should be deleted; the same is true for 17, 20 and 24 of January). Is there is any way I can deleted them at once? In other words, is there any way to get a continuous list of dates with the year included in the pivot table with having the years and months as headers?

Comment: Well, I don´t know exactly but I think you could invert the filter to show only the empty lines and after that you could select all these lines and delete them all. Is that what you want?